# React-Native send a message to email

Tags: react-native

I tried to send a message using `react-native-sms`:

```
import SendSMS from 'react-native-sms'

//some stuff

someFunction() {

    SendSMS.send({
        body: 'The default body of the SMS!',
        recipients: ['my email address'],
        successTypes: ['sent', 'queued'],
        allowAndroidSendWithoutReadPermission: true
    }, (completed, cancelled, error) => {

        console.log('SMS Callback: completed: ' + completed + ' cancelled: ' + cancelled + 'error: ' + error);

    });
}
```

But I didn't receive a message from my email. Is there any good way to send a message to email?

Comment: Do you mean this [react-native-sms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms)? It is for sending SMS, not emails.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-sms` is for sending SMS messages

There is a workaround using other apps [Medium article by Tymchyk Maksym](https://medium.com/plark/react-native-how-to-send-email-86714feaa97c)

**However** you could make a Node.js backend server and using some kind of API and [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) (or other email services) for Node.js to deliver email [Sendgrid for Node](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs)